# Prevent caret from placing after & before img tag in contenteditable div

Tags: javascript, html, css, contenteditable

This is intended to be a custom text editor, made using a contenteditable div. All the text in the screenshoot should be editable, but the blockquote itself not.

The problem I have is that caret appears before and after the image in the blockquote div. It gets placed where the blue line is represented in the screenshot. I would want to prevent this from happen, but I haven't success by the moment.

The effect I would want is to only be able to place the caret inside the blockquote's text or in the previous p tag.

[image]

Here is the html:

```css
.blockquote_img {
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    margin-right: 10px;
    user-select: none;
    -webkit-user-drag: none;
    display: block;
}

.blockquote {
    display: inline;
    margin-top: auto;
    margin-bottom: auto;
    user-select: none;
    margin-top: 10px;
}

blockquote {
    background: #eee;
    border-radius: 5px;
    margin: 16px 0;
    min-height: 40px;
}

blockquote p {
    padding: 15px;
}

.blockquote_img:before,
.blockquote_img:after {
    display: none;
}
```

```html
<div id="editor_body" contenteditable="true">

    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed ac elit at est euismod suscipit id quis purus.</p>

    <div class="blockquote">
        <span class="span_lat" style="display:inline-flex">
            <img class="blockquote_img"
                height="50px" width="50px" />
            <blockquote>
                <p>Edit this content to add your own quote</p>
            </blockquote>
        </span>
    </div>

</div>
```